# PHP to JS. Comparing code. Uncertain of purpose

Tags: php

```
<?php
$sPage = $_GET["p"];
//echo ("You picked the page: " . $sPage); 

if ($sPage == "") {
    $sPage = "home.php";
}

include($sPage);    
?>
```

It came from a php multipage website. I would like to write this same kind of code, but in javascript.
What does this code do?

http://www.tropicalteachers.com/web110/superduper/

this link is where the code came from, the php dynamic one

Comment: Which line don't you understand?  It's getting a value from the query string, setting a default value if none was found, and including another file.

Comment: tell us first what you understood from this

Comment: Php is server side and js is client side , both are different

Comment: You shouldn't do this through javascript

Comment: It's basically getting the value of query parameter "p" - checks it if it's == "" - assigns "home.php" if true - and includes final value. Though, can't say much with just 4 lines of code.

Comment: It's vulnerable to LFI attack, hopefully, its not real code.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies.I don't understand any of it. it is apart of an assignment to build a dynamic table of contents using html and js, (for a js college course, but the teacher reused work from he php class, and we are suppose to convert this to js, even though we dont know any php)

Comment: Your teacher should be fired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey so let's just start from the top to the bottom. I will try to explain shortly what each php thing does also incase you don't know PHP to well.

```
$sPage = $_GET["p"];
```

This code above is getting query parameters that you got in your URL, currently it's getting the query parameters "p" so for example if the url was http://localhost/index.php?p=hola the "$sPage" variable would hold the value "hola".

```
if($sPage == "") {  $sPage = "home.php"; }
```

Short if statement checking if there was a query parameter with a value, if not we will set the variable value to "home.php"

```
include($sPage)
```

So this will litrally just take the file "home.php" in this case and include it in page. So anything that is in the file "home.php" will be displayed on the current page you are at.

To replicate this in javascript it would be similar to using ajax to fetch the content you wanna display. Below i will link to a tutorial that can explain how to accomplish that.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp

*This doesn't help with the URL part, but that you can google yourself to with the correct termanology*

Comment: after asking around the chat board on js, this link was provided to me for guidance: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp

I believe this kind of js would suffice to replace the same thing that the php is doing. Thank you for the explaination